# Wizard failure attempting to add a razor component

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Using visual studio 2019, .NET core SDK 3.0.100-preview8-013656.  When I attempt to add a new razor component (right click on existing pages folder in an existing Blazor server-side hosted project) I get error:

*Fail to run wizard 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\AspNetCore\Web\ASP.NET\1033\RazorComponent\RazorComponent.vstemplate'  Message: No template could be found with the identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RazorComponent'*

Tried running `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates` to no effect.  I have ASP.NET and .NET Core components installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Visual Studio 2019 **Preview**

Latest version right now: 16.3.0, Preview 2